# Downloading a file to a location through a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have some api links(basically urls). On hitting these apis, zip files get downloaded.

Is this possible that I can write those up in a batch file and automate the download to some specific location in my system. Also, I want this process to act as background process.

Comment: You can do this in Powershell, but there are also many alternatives if you are able to install some software outside of Microsoft Windows. Tools like wget and curl are well known. Have a search at https://www.google.com/#q=windows+wget+equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Actually batch is capable of downloading files but it's really messy. I'd rather use powershell for this. Here is a script I've made that downloads a file and even shows you the progress:

```
function downloadFile($url, $targetFile)
{
    "Downloading $url"
    $uri = New-Object "System.Uri" "$url"
    $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($uri)
    $request.set_Timeout(15000)
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $totalLength = [System.Math]::Floor($response.get_ContentLength()/1024)
    $responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
    $targetStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $targetFile, Create
    $buffer = new-object byte[] 10KB
    $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
    $downloadedBytes = $count
    while ($count -gt 0)
    {
        [System.Console]::CursorLeft = 0
        [System.Console]::Write("Downloaded {0}K of {1}K", [System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes/1024), $totalLength)
        $targetStream.Write($buffer, 0, $count)
        $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
        $downloadedBytes = $downloadedBytes + $count
    }
    "`nFinished Download"
    $targetStream.Flush()
    $targetStream.Close()
    $targetStream.Dispose()
    $responseStream.Dispose()
}

downloadFile "URL" "target_file"
```

You only have to modify the last line by adding source and the destination.

Comment: This is nice. But how can I still download files if the site uses Windows Authentication? I need to be able to download using this script on any customer system. Could you please update it to work with a $username, $password?